# Laravel-livewire: Why does firing an event execute the render() method?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-livewire

This is the Livewire framework for Laravel

HTML:

```
<button wire:click="$emit('postAdded')">
```

PHP:

```
protected $listeners = ['postAdded' => 'showPostAddedMessage'];

public function showPostAddedMessage()
{
    // Do stuff
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.index');
}
```

Clicking the button calls showPostAddedMessage() and after that render(). How can I listen for an event without calling render()?

Comment: This is how livewire works. whenever you are changing anything / firing any event. the component will refresh. 

As far as I learned livewire, there is no way to stop it unless you are putting die() isnide showPOstAddedMessage function, which will be a very wierd way to solve it.

Comment: @fahim152 Oh, this makes sense. I have to seperate the part that loads the message and the part that sends it. Thank you very much! Could you post your comment as an answer, too so I can mark it as solved? :)

Comment: I solved my problem by nesting 2 components. The parent fires an event, the child component does not update and this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: congrats .... I didn't think of it that way. Great solution btw... 

My comment is not a solution tbh. its just a comment. it doesn't solved what you are looking for brother. It would be great if you write down your solution in the answer section so that others can get help in the future :)

Comment: @fahim152 Firing an event is the reason a component is being refreshed, your words and the answer to my question (not my problem!!!) so please add this as an answer :))

Comment: alright brother :) added

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue. In my case, the render() method was closing my parent modal box. I just added "wire:ignore" in modal div. Livewire ignores that div whenever it calls the render() method

Comment: Each time I select any item from drop down render method called and my particular div where suppose to play video get disappear, so I put wire:ignore on that div and it works.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 4):

I've came to this sort of hack: if your concern is to not re-render the view, you can just return an empty string from `render()`. The DOM will not be updated.
My case: I've got a download method that is not supposed to render anything.

```
public function download()
{
   $this->skipRender();
}

public function render()
{
    if($this->shouldSkipRender) {
        return '';
    }
    
    return view("xxxxx");
}
```

As long as I'm not missing anything, this works for me.

Comment: Thanks, you can also add "wire:ignore" to the first div in the livewire component :)

Answer (score 3):

This is how livewire works. whenever you are changing anything / firing any event. the component will refresh. As far as I learned livewire, there is no way to stop it unless you are putting die() isnide showPOstAddedMessage function, which will be a very wierd way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this problem now, there is new functionality in Livewire 3 that deals with this.

Livewire 3 `Component` has the `skipRender()` that can be called after carrying out the logic of your event handler.

```php
#[On('some_event')]
public function handleSomeEvent()
{
    -- event code here

    $this->skipRender();
}
```

Incidentally, in the documentation, there is also a `#[Renderless]` attribute that can be added to methods to indicate that they should not cause the component to be re-rendered. However, I found that this had no effect on a method that also had the `#[On]` attribute to listen for an event.

See here for more details:
https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/actions#skipping-re-renders